# Why the constructor is default while creating singleton?

Tags: java, constructor, singleton

Why is the default constructor used in this method?

```
public static TicketCounterSingle getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TicketCounterSingle();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This is the full class:

```
public class TicketCounterSingle {
    private static TicketCounterSingle instance;

    String Name;
    int avail;

    private TicketCounterSingle(String Name, int avail) {
        this.avail = avail;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public synchronized boolean bookTicket(int ticket) {
        if (avail >= ticket) {
            avail = avail - ticket;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static TicketCounterSingle getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TicketCounterSingle();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is just a default constructor? Could you show us the entire class **and** explain in detail what you cannot understand, please? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile, because there is no default constructor.

```
TicketCounterSingle() {}
```

in your class.

There is a parameterized one:

```
private TicketCounterSingle(String Name, int avail) {
    this.avail = avail;
    this.Name = Name;
}
```

That means the default constructor will not be provided automatically, and you either have to provide a default constructor or call the parameterized one in a parameterized `getInstance(String name, int avail)` method:

```
public static TicketCounterSingle getInstance(String name, int avail) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TicketCounterSingle(String name, int avail);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: The constructor TicketCounterSingle() is undefined compilation error

Comment: @Nisha That's exactly what I tried to answer... Either define one or use the one that has arguments.